# FileSystemException: readSync failed, path = ....app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk' (OS Error: The operation completed successfully. , errno = 0)

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I am failing to run my Flutter application getting the error below after upgrading to Android Studio version 4.2

Error code: FileSystemException: readSync failed, path = 'C:\project\project_name\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk' (OS Error: The operation completed successfully.
, errno = 0)

I have reinstalled Android and still getting the same error.

flutter doctor output:
C:\Users<user_profile>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 2.1.0-11.0.pre.29, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1165], locale en-AU)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio
[√] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
[√] Connected device (2 available)
```

• No issues found!

Flutter crash report.
Please report a bug at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.

### command

flutter build apk --debug

### exception

FileSystemException: FileSystemException: readSync failed, path = 'C:\project\app_name\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk' (OS Error: The operation completed successfully.
, errno = 0)

```
#0      _RandomAccessFile.readSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:760:7)
#1      _File.readAsBytesSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:552:23)
#2      ForwardingFile.readAsBytesSync (package:file/src/forwarding/forwarding_file.dart:88:43)
#3      ForwardingFile.readAsBytesSync (package:file/src/forwarding/forwarding_file.dart:88:43)
#4      _calculateSha (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:849:32)
#5      AndroidGradleBuilder.buildGradleApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:526:34)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      AndroidGradleBuilder.buildApk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:230:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      BuildApkCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_apk.dart:105:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1186:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1037:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:152:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:151:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:283:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:152:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#15     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:151:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#16     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:239:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#17     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#18     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:60:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#19     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:152:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#20     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:151:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#21     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:77:10)
<asynchronous suspension>
#22     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:92:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

### flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 2.1.0-11.0.pre.29, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1165], locale en-AU)
    • Flutter version 2.1.0-11.0.pre.29 at D:\development\flutter
    • Framework revision 7dbd586e04 (7 months ago), 2021-02-26 22:10:19 -0800
    • Engine revision 3dbf9638d2
    • Dart version 2.13.0 (build 2.13.0-79.0.dev)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at D:\development\android-sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = D:\development\android-sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[✓] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • android-studio-dir = C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\prude\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.20.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)                       • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 93.0.4577.63
    • Edge (web)                         • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 93.0.961.38

• No issues found!
```

Comment: You can try the steps given here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/42072

Comment: tried: but I am still getting the same erro
flutter clean
flutter pub get

Comment: Please update your answer with output from `flutter doctor -v`

Comment: Updated - still getting the

Comment: Update the question with more detailed log of the issue, or the Crash Report

Comment: I have added the Flutter crush report

Comment: Try updating the Flutter SDK, it may have been fixed in the latest release and also update the question with minimal, reproducible code.

Comment: updating the Flutter SDK did not fix the issue. Could you please clarify how you would like me to update the question with reproducible code?

I am now getting this error:
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
   > integer overflow